# jQuery function when screen resizing

Tags: jquery, screen

I want to add a class to an element when the screen width is smaller than 979px. Also when the screen is adjusting and wider than 979px, above added class should be removed.

This is the code I've tried, but its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(screen.width < 979) {
       $('.social').addClass('hide');
   }
});
```

Please help me fix this.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: you can do this with `@media` query in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 979) {
      $('.social').addClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('.social').removeClass('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Haha... I should've posted a solution instead of a link! Vote up.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Good for me :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need: [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).